# An error faced using vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector

Well in my program i have made a class of name 'Transition'.
When i made a vector of Transition type named delta_.
And when later in one of my functions implementation of the class where i have declared delta_, i tried to use iterator with the syntax given below:

```
vector<Transition>::iterator it;
it=this->delta_.begin();
```

i got these two errors:

> In constructor `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, *Container>::*_normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iter, _Container>&) [with _Iter = const Fa::Transition*, _Iterator = Fa::Transition*, _Container = std::vector >]':
>
> invalid conversion from `const Fa::Transition* const' to`Fa::Transition*'

Now i really have no idea where the mistake is. Can anybody please help!!

Comment: We need more code to precisely explain what's going on here. It appears that you're attempting an illegal type conversion from a constant type to a mutable one, which throws a compiler error in C++. The most likely cause is unexpected constness within class `Transition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess, are you doing `it=this->delta_.begin();` in a `const` method of the class,  and `delta_` is a member of the class?

A constness of the method guarantees that members of the class will not changed. But the variable `it` has non-const type `iterator`, and that gives possibility to change the member `delta_` which makes the protection corrupt.

The `std::vector` has two overloaded methods `begin()`

```
iterator begin ();
const_iterator begin () const;
```

If you use `begin()` in a method which is `const`, compiler calls second one.

So you need to refuse from constness of the method, or use `const_iterator`.

Another possible way, which I do not recommend because of blurring constness of the object, is to put your vector on a heap and operate with a pointer to it.

Comment: the same thing happened to me recently )) glad to help you.

Comment: So what can i do to get rid off this error? and why const method making iterator to return a const_iterator?

Answer (score 1):

Either `this` or `delta_` seems to be `const`, causing `begin()` to return a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Neither this or delta_ r constant rather the function in which iam declaring it is constant.

Comment: That's just about what I meant. In a `const` function the type of `this` will be `const type*`.

Comment: ok,so what can i do to get rid off this error? and why const method making iterator to return a const_iterator?

Comment: Making `it` a const_iterator would let you assign the returned value to it.